# How to include a custom text in page numbers?

Tags: page-numbering

I'd like to realise page numbers like "Type 1 Page 1" and "Type 1 Page 2" and so on in my document. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Manupulate page numbers (and header-footer in general) with `fancyhdr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to get some text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\lhead{} % I have added all possibilities to add
%\chead{} %  text to header and footer but commented them out
%\rhead{} %   uncomment and try
%\lfoot{}
\cfoot{Type 1 Page \thepage}
%\rfoot{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

See the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) documentation for details

Comment: Thanks so much. I worked well but when I add \maketitle into my document, the page numbering goes back to 1, 2, 3, ...
Can you help me out please!

Comment: @Fizzle, the problem of different layout on the first page is a feature of fancyhdr. The purpose is t okeep the titlepage clean.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `\documentclass{article}` at the head of your file this should happen automatically, otherwise you can use `\setcounter{page}{number}` to manually begin adding numbers where if you put it on the first page you will want to change `{number}` to `{1}`.