# how do i get header like

Tags: header-footer

```
Name                                                                           Chapter name
roll No.
___________________________________________________________________________________________


content


___________________________________________________________________________________________
University name                                                                    page No.
```

Comment: Check out [the manual](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) for the `fancyhdr` package. [This post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94287/how-to-include-a-custom-text-in-page-numbers) answers the part of your question that has to do with page numbering.

Comment: [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that uses the [`fancyhdr`](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) package.

**Edit:** You can get the section name to appear on the right side of the table header using the `nameref` package. I have modified the solution to do this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{%
    Name\\
    Roll Number%
}
\chead{}
\rhead{\itshape\nameref{chapter}\\}    
\lfoot{University Name}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\section{Carrot Cake}\label{chapter}
\noindent
Yellow matter custard, green slop pie,\\
All mixed together with a dead dog's eye,\\
Slap it on a butty, ten foot thick,\\
Then wash it all down with a cup of cold sick.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to consider to place your `fancyhdr` set up in the preamble. `:)`

Comment: @hpesoj626 Good point, I fixed it now.

Comment: I know this thing.but i can't get the actual chapter name using \chaptertitle in \rhead

Comment: @Darshna Ok, I've modified the answer to do that. Is this what you were looking for?